# Html Form Unable to Validate Inputs using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms, html

I am creating an application.  The HTML file is like the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body style="background-color: #ccc">

        <script type="javascript">
            function validateform(){
                alert("Hello");
                var firstnameErr="";
                var valid = true;
                var name = document.myform.fname.value;
                var types = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;

                if (fname==null || fname=="") {
                    firstnameErr = "required";
                    valid = false;
                } else if (!fname.value.match(types)) {
                    firstnameErr = "format error";
                    valid = false;
                }
                return valid;
            }
        </script>

        <form name="myform" method="post" onsubmit="return  validateform()" action="/Project/ViewList.php">
            Firstname : <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name" maxlength="20"> 
            <span class="error">*
                <script type="javascript"> 
                    document.write(firstnameErr);
                </script>
            </span>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

When I click on the submit button, it straightaway redirects to "ViewList.php" without seeming to run validatefom(). I added the alert() to check whether the function is executing or not. I want my form to submit only when it meets the validation requirements, not when **valid** is false.

Comment: see [HTML5 form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation)

Comment: Your method is named `validate()` but you are calling `validateform()` in the onsubmit attribute.

Comment: I am using validateform() in my original code. This a typo while writing the question

Comment: `onsubmit="validateform"` should be enough I think - but then again I haven't written inline event handlers in years, and neither should you tbh.

Answer (score 1):

Besides Typo errors, The main problem that I found is your script is not get executed and your `validateform()` method is not available. It happened **because your script tag `type` attribute is not correct** `<script type="javascript">`

*To make it work you need to change it to this*
`<script type="text/javascript">`

And please change your validation method `validateform()` as it has too may typo.

Comment: Typos are been corrected and the type is change to text/javascript but still the problem is unsolved, I removed the form tag and validated using jquery and now able to display the error tags but I am unable to use the POST method for sending variables.

Comment: Why have you removed the form tags.

Comment: because post method is refreshing the page, so the errors are not showed once I click on submit button

Comment: But that is not a solution.Can you update the code in your question

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with the code is that the OP is validating the old-fashioned way with an HTML5 form.  Prior to HTML5, you had to use JavaScript for front-end validation; now things are much simpler and easier, too.  Of course, the OP would replace the value of the action in the following example with the desired URL.

Note: there were errors in the OP's code, but if you get rid of the JavaScript and code the HTML making sure to add the following to the text input:

```
required pattern="[a-zA-Z]+"
```

then the form validates.  In other words, you don't have to work so hard when you use [**HTML5 for form validation**](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/) :)

```html
<form id="myform" name="myform" method="POST" action="https://www.example.com">
  <label for="fname">Firstname</label>: <input name="fname"  placeholder="First name"  maxlength="20" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]+">
  <input type="submit"  name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

For those who prefer to do things the old-fashioned way, see this  [**revision**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xrmRRE) of the OP's code.  Note: it uses a minimum of variables, employs short-cuts for less verbosity, and is organized with functions.  Also, it is kind to the user's hands, too.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have done you will never be able to use document.write to output anything, use this, working for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
    <script>
        function validateform(){
            alert("Hello");

            var valid = true;
            var fname = document.myform.fname.value;

            var types = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
            if (fname==null || fname=="") {
                firstnameErr = 'required';
                valid = false;
            } else if (!fname.match(types)) {
                firstnameErr = 'format error';
                valid = false;
            }
            document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = firstnameErr;
            return valid;
        }
    </script>

    <form name="myform" method="post" onsubmit="return validateform()" action="/Project/ViewList.php">
        Firstname : <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name" maxlength="20"> 
        <span class="error">* <label id='msg'></label> </span>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

</body>
```

Comment: I want to display the error message beside the input field and not as an alert.

Comment: In your case you are defining the var firstnameErr inside the function so how can you use it in document.write???

Comment: Check the updated code above, works now like the way u want but approach is different.

Answer (score 0):

It looks you have a series of typo in your code,
try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body style="background-color: #ccc">

    <script>
        function validateform() {         
            var firstnameErr = "";
            var valid = true;
            var name = document.myform.fname.value;
            var types = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;

            if (name == null || name == "") {
                firstnameErr = "required";
                valid = false;
            } else if (!name.match(types)) {
                firstnameErr = "format error";
                valid = false;
            }
            return valid;
        }
    </script>

    <form name="myform" method="post" onsubmit="return validateform()" action="/Project/ViewList.php">
        Firstname : <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name" maxlength="20">
        <span class="error">*
                <script> 
                    document.write(firstnameErr);
                </script>
            </span>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I corrected the typos and tried to run your function, it is still not validating and is redirecting to next page on clicking Submit button

Comment: I update my answer, and btw nowadays you can a simple tag <script> omitting the attribute type.
check it out